# Regular expressions: match text inside delimiters

Tags: regex, sed, grep, greedy

I will try to be as much clear as possible, hoping this question will be helpful for other people having the same problem.

In my file.txt I would like to match with the commands "grep" and "sed" only the text inside "(" and ")". Example:

```
This is my line and (this is the text to match!), and bla bla bla...
```

But some line could look like:

```
Another line (text to match 1;) something else, (text to match 2 )
```

Here the problems:
Expressions like 
`grep '(.*)' file.txt` or `sed 's/(.*)//' <file.txt` 
will not work because `.*` is by default greedy.
 That means, it will match the second example like this:
 Another line ( **text to match 1;) something else, (text to match 2** )

The solutions must be a non-greedy matching, then I tried to use the non-greedy quantifier `?`.

```
grep -E '\(.*?\)' file.txt
```

or with sed

```
sed -r 's/\(.*\)//' <file.txt
```

In this case we need to use `-E` and `-r` to make grep and sed read extended expressions, and we also need to use `\` before `(`.
But even this solution doesn't seem to work, I don't know why.
Then I tried something like:

```
grep '(.*)[^(]*' file.txt
```

in order to find the lines with only one "(text to match)" and, if i would like for example to rewrite the text inside the (), the syntax would be:

```
sed 's/(.*)\([^(]*\)/(new text)\1/'<file.txt
```

But while it seems to work I discover that`'(.*)[^(]*'` match some line like the old `(.*)` (that's a mistery...)

Any better solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to help you out, `'(.*)[^(]*'` is the same as '(.*)', because the first is greedily matching everything it can before going to the next, and since the next also has an asterisk quantifier, it is matching 0 times, because the `.*` matched everything. Also, excellent job explaining what you've tried. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I understand what you mean, I thought  `[^(]* ` will exactly stop when it meets a `(`, but actually it will never meet one because ` .* `
matched already them all.

Comment: Yes, precisely! Good job :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this regex should work:

```
\(([^\)]+)\)/g
```

as you can see here it works :

https://regex101.com/r/rR2uF3/1

Comment: Glad it works. Please accept my answer by selecting the tick next to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Using gnu awk it is pretty easy:

```
s='Another line (text to match 1;) something else, (text to match 2 )'

awk 'BEGIN{ FPAT="\\([^)]*\\)" } {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}' <<< "$s"
(text to match 1;)
(text to match 2 )
```

Comment: This may need  `gnu awk` due to  `FPAT`

Answer (score 1):

All you need is:

```
$ cat file
Another line (text to match 1;) something else, (text to match 2 )

$ sed 's/(\([^)]*\)/(foo/' file
Another line (foo) something else, (text to match 2 )

$ sed 's/(\([^)]*\)/(foo/2' file
Another line (text to match 1;) something else, (foo)

$ sed 's/(\([^)]*\)/(foo/g' file
Another line (foo) something else, (foo)
```

The non-greedy quantifier `?` is never needed and rarely useful enough to warrant how much harder it makes your regexps to read/understand. It also isn't supported by all tools. When debugging "greedy" matching problems, always start by changing `.*` if present to `[^x]*` where `x` is whatever character comes right after the string you're interested in, a `)` in this case.